# iOS UINavigationController switching rootviewcontroller based on condition

Tags: ios, storyboard, navigationcontroller

I am writing an iOS application using storyboard.

I created `ViewControllerA`, `ViewControllerB` and then embedded `ViewControllerA` in a `UINavigationController` on the storyboard.

The app will show `ViewControllerA` when it is first launched, otherwise it will show `ViewControllerB`.

I added launch history check code successfully. I am going to set the `UINavigationController` as the window's `rootViewController` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

The problem is that I cannot get the `UINavigationController` from the storyboard, so I can't push `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB` based on my condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a storyboard then the `UINavigationController` should be set as the initial view controller and it will be loaded and displayed automatically. Now, when something happens in `ViewControllerA` it can push `ViewControllerB` by using:

```
ViewControllerB *b = ...;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:b animated:YES];
```

---

For enhanced tampering, the app delegate has a `window` property. From here you can get the `rootViewController`. Cast that to the `UINavigationController` and you can modify / push. Set it to something else and you can replace the `UINavigationController` all together.

Comment: I want to show ViewControllerA or ViewControllerB as the first screen.
In the above method, can I hide ViewControllerA?

Comment: If I add above code in the appdelegate, how can I get ViewControllerA and B from storyboard in the appdelegate?

[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerA"];

I found this code, but self.storyboard is invalid in appdelegate.